# подключение yii.validation.js и yii.activeForm.js

Tags: yii2

Не могу понять как подключаются эти файлы. Мне надо, чтоб в коде страницы появилось

```
<script src="/assets/d09ddd6/yii.validation.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/d09ddd6/yii.activeForm.js"></script>
```

логически понимаю, что прямые ссылки ставить на них не правильно.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetbundle

Answer (score 0):

```
use yii\validators\ValidationAsset;
use yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset;

ValidationAsset::register($this);
ActiveFormAsset::register($this);
```